# Word for student's notebook

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english

What is the American word for a notebook that students have at school in which they do their homework assignments?  I mean the notebook in which a teacher marks good or bad behavior of a student and which parents have to sign weekly.

Comment: My kids' schools called it *a planner*. (That's what we had to sign to acknowledge that we saw the assignments. The teachers my children had didn't use it to write comments, but I guess they could have.)

Comment: "Parents have to sign weekly?"

Comment: @tchrist Yes, that's not uncommon.

Comment: @MarkBeadles What grade level?  The only thing I can think of in the US was a part of our report card back in early gradeschool (around 8 years old)

Comment: @Izkata Well, I can't tell from your comment when that might have been. But here in parts of Ohio, USA, from no later than 2000-present these planners have been required from late elementary through middle school (ages 7-12). They are not limited to here - they are standard tools available at a national level from many vendors.

Comment: @MarkBeadles The time era I'm thinking of was ~1996-97 in Illinois, and I don't recall anything for the "good or bad behavior" usage beyond 4th grade (age 10, ~1998-1999 for me).  As for homework, we just do them in "notebooks".  =)

Comment: @Izkata: (This alludes to a possible ambiguity in Monica's question) The agendas and planners that we're talking about are primarily designed to be a standard vehicle for teachers and parents to communicate; students actually _do_ their homework in standard notebooks, but they _record_ their assignments in planners/agendas (although many planners have extra paper where some homework could be done). In the school districts around where I live, these were rather popular for awhile, but I think they're being phased out in many places, as more schools get an online presence to handle such matters.

Comment: My Russian dictionary says it is 'school record book', but sometimes it has words that native speakers never use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my son's present school, they have a book they call an "agenda" where the student is supposed to write assignments and that sort of thing.

I have four kids, the youngest now in his second year of high school, and they've attended schools in three different districts in two states, and no school has ever asked me to sign anything like that, weekly or otherwise. When I was a kid my parents were never asked to sign anything like that as far as I recall. Maybe that's a British thing, or if it's done in the U.S., it's not universal. Whether my kids' schools were the exception or the rule I have no idea.

Comment: I never heard of this practice in British schools. It's probably from non-English speaking parts of the world.

Comment: I'm from the UK. When I was at school, there was a "Homework Diary", and it had that printed on the front. Very few children had that imposed on them and their parents by the school, but it remained an option for every pupil. [I tried it for a while. Didn't help!]

Comment: I'm in the U.S. and so is Mark Beadles.

Comment: My kids (4 of them, U.S. family) all had _planners_ (which were sometimes called _agendas_). Seems like the parental signature arrangement could be invoked from time to time, particularly around the middle school timeframe, if the student had been performing badly due to incomplete assignments, but it wasn't necessarily every week for every parent.

Answer (score 6):

I agree with @JLG in his comment - we (US family with kids in school) call this a **planner** or **[student planner](https://www.google.com/search?sugexp=chrome,mod=5&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=student%20planner)**.

Comment: It seems that 1. this is a newer (2000 or later) thing and 2. it is widespread but by no means universal in the US.

Answer (score 2):

[**Composition book**](http://www.officedepot.com/a/browse/composition-books/N=5+502638/), perhaps?  (The link is to a product search at Office Depot, so you can verify whether it's what you meant.)

Comment: A composition book is more generic, generally just a bound blank book.

Comment: I don't have kids, and my elementary school days are lost in the mists of time.  We had Pee-Chees, and later Trappers (and Trapper Keepers), but the only thing I ever had in which I essentially carried communications back and forth between my teachers and parents was in high school English - and it was a composition book (fake-marble cover, quad-ruled pages.)  So I suspect that my education didn't include the precise thing that the OP is asking about...

Answer (score 1):

The word 'composition notebook' is generally  used in the US to describe one of these notebooks:

[image: A composition notebook]

'Planner' is more widely used to describe what you're saying.